# Format datetime.utcnow() time

Tags: python, datetime

I have saved a time as `presentTime=datetime.datetime.utcnow()`

It 's output is 2014-08-18 21:11:35.537000. How can this be formatted to : August 18 2014 - 21:11:35 instead?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`datetime.utcnow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow) returns a [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object. You can use its [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) method to convert it into a string of your desired format:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%B %d %Y - %H:%M:%S')
'August 20 2014 - 13:55:49'
```

Answer (score 2):

the object you're getting is a `datetime` instance. Just format it via its method `strftime()`:
https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html?highlight=date#datetime.datetime.strftime

**update** (thx @Ffisegyedd):

possible placeholders values: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior in particular has the meanings of the different formatters.

Answer (score 2):

```
import datetime

presentTime=datetime.datetime.utcnow()
print presentTime.strftime('%B %d %Y - %H:%M:%S')
```